# usage of custom npm packages using vue-loader

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, webpack-2, vue-loader

I set up my project with `vue-loader` and added few `postcss` plugins in the `postcss` config file.

I want to use the `GSAP` package (from `npm`), where do I put the code so that `webpack` can register it?

Answer (score 0):

Just like any other package, just `npm install gsap --save`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [gurghet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440237), you would first have to install the package by running the suggested command

```bash
npm install gsap --save
```

Then to use the package you would have to import the needed modules from the package in your own code as follows

```js
// Typical import
import {TweenMax, Power2, TimelineLite} from "gsap";

// Or get to the parts that aren't included inside TweenMax (works as of 1.19.1):
import Draggable from "gsap/Draggable";
import ScrollToPlugin from "gsap/ScrollToPlugin";
```

This is pretty much the same install procedure listed at [npmjs.com/package/gsap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gsap#npm)